# How to call asyncTasks periodically

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have two AsyncTasks doing network operations. I want to call them periodically (like after one min.). How do I do that? I dont think I can do it on the UI thread. Do i need to create a new thread? Is it possible to implemet this without AlarmManager/Service?

Basically I want to exectue these two statements periodically after one min.

```
new UploadAsyncTask().execute();
new DownloadAsyncTask().execute();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use a timer.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {       
     @Override
     public void run() {
       handler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {  
             new UploadAsyncTask().execute();
             new DownloadAsyncTask().execute();
          }
        });
      }
};
timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000); //it executes this every 1000ms
```

Comment: on another thread than the UI thread. Basically the doc said _" Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue"_. You can find more explanation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: why should call using handler? TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {       
     @Override
     public void run() {
             new UploadAsyncTask().execute();
             new DownloadAsyncTask().execute();
      }
}; Is that way possible?